# SSL/TLS connection not working in webclient after being in background

Tags: vb.net

So if I use my program normally no error occurs. But if it is in background for longer time and I use the webclient to visit a web address it immidiately throws `could not create a SSL/TLS secure channel` error but if I try again the error dissapears. I already set the TLS to 1.2 and expect100continue to false.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class CinemaLinker
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MaximizeBox = False
        If Not HaveInternetConnection() Then
            MessageBox.Show("Warning: no internet connection!")
        End If
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    End Sub

    Public Property TextFromBox As String
    Public Property StatusLink As String
    Private Client As New WebClient
Private GoogleSearch = "****"
Private BingSearch = "*****"
Private AskSearch = "*****"

Private Sub Search() Handles Button1.Click
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
    TextFromBox = RichTextBox1.Text
    If Button3.Enabled And Button4.Enabled Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a category!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TextFromBox.Contains("Type movie or tv series name here") Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextFromBox) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextFromBox) Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        If Not Button3.Enabled Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please type the name of the movie!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not Button4.Enabled Then
            If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox3.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox3.Text) Or RichTextBox3.Text.Contains("E")) Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                MessageBox.Show("Please type the name of the tv series! Episode number missing!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox2.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox2.Text) Or RichTextBox2.Text.Contains("S") Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                MessageBox.Show("Please type the name of the tv series! Season and episode numbers missing!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
            MessageBox.Show("Please type the name of the tv series!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Not Button4.Enabled Then
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox3.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox3.Text) Or RichTextBox3.Text.Contains("E") Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox2.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox2.Text) Or RichTextBox2.Text.Contains("S") Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                MessageBox.Show("Season and episode numbers missing!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
            MessageBox.Show("Episode number missing!")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox2.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox2.Text) Or RichTextBox2.Text.Contains("S") Then
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
            MessageBox.Show("Season number missing!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Not HaveInternetConnection() Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        MessageBox.Show("No internet connection!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim ImdbURL As String = getIMDbUrl(TextFromBox)
    If Not ImdbURL.Contains("******") And Not Button3.Enabled Then
        ImdbURL = getIMDbUrl(TextFromBox) + " movie"
        If Not ImdbURL.Contains("***") And Not Button3.Enabled Then
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
            MessageBox.Show("Movie not found! Please add the year in the name!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If Not ImdbURL.Contains("***") And Not Button4.Enabled Then
        ImdbURL = getIMDbUrl(TextFromBox) + " TV series"
        If Not ImdbURL.Contains("****") And Not Button4.Enabled Then
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
            MessageBox.Show("TV series not found! Please add the year in the name!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Dim LinkFinal As String = (GetLink(ImdbURL))
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkFinal) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LinkFinal) Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Clipboard.SetText(LinkFinal)
    MessageBox.Show("Link in clipboard. Paste it into desired browser!")
    TextFromBox = String.Empty
    StatusLink = "0"
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
End Sub

Public Function HaveInternetConnection() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    Try
        result = My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com")
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = False
    End Try
    Return result
End Function

Private Function GetIP() As String
    Return Client.DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org").ToString()
End Function

Private Function matchAll(ByVal regex As String, ByVal html As String, ByVal Optional i As Integer = 1) As ArrayList
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    For Each m As Match In New Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(html)
        list.Add(m.Groups(i).Value.Trim())
    Next

    Return list
End Function

Private Function getIMDbUrl(MovieName As String, Optional searchEngine As String = "google") As String
    Dim address As String = GoogleSearch + MovieName
    If searchEngine.ToLower().Equals("bing") Then
        address = BingSearch + MovieName
    End If
    If searchEngine.ToLower().Equals("ask") Then
        address = AskSearch + MovieName
    End If
    Dim html As String = Client.DownloadString(address)
    Dim arrayList As ArrayList = matchAll("<a href=""(*****\d{7}/)"".*?>.*?</a>", html, 1)
    If arrayList.Count > 0 Then
        Return CStr(arrayList(0))
    ElseIf searchEngine.ToLower().Equals("google") Then
        Return getIMDbUrl(MovieName, "bing")
    ElseIf searchEngine.ToLower().Equals("bing") Then
        Return getIMDbUrl(MovieName, "ask")
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetLink(ImdbURL As String) As Object
    Dim ID = ImdbURL.Replace("*****/", "")
    ID = ID.Replace("/", "")
    Dim result As Object
    If StatusLink = "1" Then
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Not Button4.Enabled Then
        Dim SeasonNumber As String = "&s=" + RichTextBox2.Text
        Dim EpisodeNumber As String = "&e=" + RichTextBox3.Text
        Dim TVSeasonNumber As String = "&tv=1" + SeasonNumber
        If Not Client.DownloadString("*****/" & ID).Contains(">Episode Guide<") Then
            ImdbURL = getIMDbUrl(TextFromBox + " TV series")
            StatusLink = "1"
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImdbURL) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImdbURL) Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                MessageBox.Show("TV series not found! Please add the year in the name or check category!")
                result = String.Empty
                Exit Function
            Else
                ID = ImdbURL.Replace("*****", "")
                ID = ID.Replace("/", "")
                result = (GetLink(ImdbURL))
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) Then
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                    MessageBox.Show("TV series not found! Please add the year in the name or check category!")
                    result = String.Empty
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Return result.ToString()
                    result = String.Empty
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Dim address As String = "******" & ID & TVSeasonNumber & "&ip=" & GetIP()
            Dim token As String = Client.DownloadString(address)
            result = "*****" & ID & TVSeasonNumber & EpisodeNumber & "&ticket=" & token
            Return result.ToString
            Exit Function
        End If
    ElseIf Not Button3.Enabled Then
        If Client.DownloadString("****" & ID).Contains(">Episode Guide<") Then
            ImdbURL = getIMDbUrl(TextFromBox + " movie",)
            StatusLink = "1"
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImdbURL) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ImdbURL) Then
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                MessageBox.Show("Movie not found! Please add the year in the name or check category!")
                result = String.Empty
                Exit Function
            Else
                ID = ImdbURL.Replace("****", "")
                ID = ID.Replace("/", "")
                result = (GetLink(ImdbURL))
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) Then
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.[Default]
                    MessageBox.Show("Movie not found! Please add the year in the name or check category!")
                    result = String.Empty
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Return result.ToString()
                    result = String.Empty
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Dim address2 As String = "****" & ID & "&ip=" & GetIP()
            Dim token2 As String = Client.DownloadString(address2)
            result = "****" & ID & "&ticket=" & token2
            Return result.ToString
            result = String.Empty
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
#Disable Warning BC42105 ' Function doesn't return a value on all code paths
End Function

Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.GotFocus
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("Type movie or tv series name here") Then RichTextBox1.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.GotFocus
    If RichTextBox2.Text.Contains("S") Then RichTextBox2.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox3_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox3.GotFocus
    If RichTextBox3.Text.Contains("E") Then RichTextBox3.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Button4.Enabled = True
    RichTextBox1.Enabled = True
    RichTextBox2.Enabled = False
    RichTextBox3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Button4.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = True
    RichTextBox1.Enabled = True
    RichTextBox2.Enabled = True
    RichTextBox3.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If CType(e, KeyPressEventArgs).KeyChar = vbCr Then
        Search()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox3.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If CType(e, KeyPressEventArgs).KeyChar = vbCr Then
        Search()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    If CType(e, KeyPressEventArgs).KeyChar = vbCr Then
        Search()
    End If
    If Char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar) Then e.KeyChar = Char.ToLower(e.KeyChar)
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_Lostfocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.LostFocus
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox1.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox1.Text) Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = "Type movie or tv series name here..."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_Lostfocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.LostFocus
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox2.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox2.Text) Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = "S:"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox3_Lostfocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox3.LostFocus
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox3.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RichTextBox3.Text) Then
        RichTextBox3.Text = "E:"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    StatusLink = "0"
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.TextChanged
    StatusLink = "0"
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox3.TextChanged
    StatusLink = "0"
End Sub
End Class
```

all of the ***** are https website addresses.
Tried switching the Net version to 4.7. Did not help. It is also legal in my country to stream (interior minister dropped a bomb on the DMCA here lol) and this is streaming only. The code is not operational so i had not given you anything dangerous if it is illegal in yours.

Comment: You mean `Expect100Continue = False`, right? What happens when your app is *in the background*? What kind of app is this? Is it a timed event? How the connections are created? Can you post the code that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: It is just a simple code that generates a few strings, visits a few websites and returns a few values as strings that are used further to generate a new string which is then ultimately visited. The most complicated events are downloading a webpage as string and regex.

Comment: So, since it's simple code, it won't take much effort to post it.

Comment: OK gimme a second

Comment: there. done. but it wont help ya much i think.

Comment: 99% if this code is unrelated to the question. Anyway, you have to specify `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` before a connection is created, in the same scope where the connection is created. Thus, make a method where you instantiate a WebClient class and use this method to perform the downloads. It would be **MUCH** better to use a static HttpCient class instead of WebClient if your app needs to create connection for an undetermined amount of time. Connections are not unlimited and you need to try to reuse them. A static HttpClient is designed for this

Comment: Note that you also need to add a [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback): when a server requires you to validate its certificate(s), if you don't have a callback that answers to the request, the TLS handshake is terminated in the same way.

Comment: A last thing: looking at this code, it's really not clear how this can work *in the background*. It's not built to work like that in any way I can see.

Comment: it works in the background. Just the webclient error. Dk what u mean. will do method.